# Can I lock a Sql table in Sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to lock a sql table in Sql server 2012.The need is that the table should be opened by the admin only.

Comment: Are you talking about user permissions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql

Comment: Sir,Actually i have  a table called tbl_login.if i set the username and password.other than me no one cannot change the field.

Comment: Don't store passwords. Store password hashes. For the "lock" you want, that is handled via table permissions.

Comment: [Use salt & hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), don't allow your user to directly access the DB. If the db is distributed to the user, encrypt the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the Userprofileid is of Admin with roleName as Admin.
Example :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedurename 
 (@UserProfileid BIGINT) 
            AS 
                SET nocount ON; 

              BEGIN 
                  IF( (SELECT R.NAME 
                       FROM   trn_userprofile UP(nolock) 
                              INNER JOIN aspnetusers U(nolock) 
                                      ON u.id = up.userid 
                              INNER JOIN dbo.aspnetuserroles UR(nolock) 
                                      ON U.id = UR.userid 
                              INNER JOIN dbo.aspnetroles R(nolock) 
                                      ON UR.roleid = R.id 
                       WHERE  UP.userprofileid = @UserProfileid 
                              AND UP.isactive = 1 
                              AND UP.isdeleted = 0) = 'Admin' ) 
                    BEGIN 
                        SELECT * 
                        FROM   tablename 
                    END; 
              END;
```

Comment: sir after one insertion i want to lock a particular field.

Comment: @Neetha in your table add Author or CreatedBy or PostedBy Column , Then in where clause mention CreatedBy=@CreatedBy.